# .gitignore match folder substring

Tags: git, gitignore

I have folders in a project that always have `.X` at the end. In each of these folders, subfolders must be ignored. I am not able to get the filter to work. The `.X` part must be matched.

Example directory:

```
.git
foo/one.X/folder_to_ignore
bar/two.X/folder_to_ignore
```

Thins I tried, that did not work:

```
*.X/folder_to_ignore
*X/folder_to_ignore
**.X/folder_to_ignore
**X/folder_to_ignore
*.*.X/folder_to_ignore (regex?)
```

And some other variations of that sort.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```sh
*.X/folder_to_ignore/
**/*.X/folder_to_ignore/
```

Let me know if it worked.

Comment: `**/*.X/folder_to_ignore/` worked! Thanks. Strange combination

Comment: Well! Please accept my answer. (It is not so strange :) )

Comment: Accepted now, I had to wait 10 minutes before I could accept :)